# Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class

Tags: symfony

I've this error when I'am trying to access to: `localhost/lab/web/app_dev.php/login`

> Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class ET\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController

I've searched if it was link to namespace or class name but I don't know :

My SecurityController:

```
namespace ET\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{

public function loginAction(Request $request)
{

// Si le visiteur est déjà identifié, on le redirige vers l'accueil
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {

      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('oc_platform_accueil'));

}


$session = $request->getSession();


// On vérifie s'il y a des erreurs d'une précédente soumission du formulaire

if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {

  $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);

} else {

  $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);

  $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);

}


return $this->render('ETUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(

  // Valeur du précédent nom d'utilisateur entré par l'internaute

  'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),

  'error'         => $error,

));
}
}
```

My app/config/routing.yml:

```
login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: ETUserBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
 pattern:   /login_check


logout:
pattern:   /logout
```

And my app/config/security.yml :

```
security:

firewalls:
    # ...
    main:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider:  in_memory
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        logout:
            path:   logout
            target: /platform
```

Anyone has an idea please ? 
N.B : I've tried the same code on a fresh installation of Symfony 2.7 and 2.6

Comment: what about the difference of `ET\UserBundle\`  and   `OC\UserBundle `

Comment: Just a missplay by writing the code her, I will update my post

Comment: Is it possible you have another PHP file elsewhere in your app which has the same namespace (regardless of the location of the file) and class name, due to a copy/paste which hasn't been amended?

Comment: I don't think because I've tried this code on a new installation of Symfony v2.6 and 2.7.

Comment: Yep.  You have another class called SecurityController somewhere.  You can show this by changing the name to something like SecurityXController.  But eventually you need to track down the duplicate.

Comment: Okay this is very strange, I just pressed F5 and the error changed in `The autoloader expected class "ET\Bunle\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController" to be defined in file "C:\xampp\htdocs\lab/src/ET/Bundle\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.` **How to fix it now please ??**

Comment: Change `ET\Bunle` to `ET\Bundle` in the namespace declaration.

Comment: Again a missclick by retriving manually the error :/ 
The error specify for expected class : `"ET\Bundle\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController"`